# Twilio - com.twilio.exception.ApiException: Upgrade Required

Tags: java, twilio, twilio-api

We have 3 different Twilio accounts, one for production, testing and development.

For some reason when we use the testing account it return a message: Upgrade is Required.

We are using the Twilio 8.24 library and java.

Reading I found that the error is related to the TLS 1.2 that is requiered, we force the request adding to the JVM the -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2 command but the error persist.

The strange is that the same code works perfect with the production or development account, it only display the error with the testing account.

The Code is very simple:

`Twilio.init(SID, TOKEN);`
`com.twilio.rest.lookups.v1.PhoneNumber number = com.twilio.rest.lookups.v1.PhoneNumber.fetcher(new PhoneNumber(787-123-4567)).fetch();`

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Is it possible that in the testing environment you may be forcing TLS 1.2 but still using a weak cipher that Twilio no longer accepts?

Please read through this [article for various things to check and test with to ensure that your environment can connect to Twilio](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360006751753-Tips-for-Upgrading-Your-Environment-to-Support-Twilio-REST-API-s-TLS-and-Strong-Cipher-Suite-Changes).